# Integral notation in Shifrin's *Multivariable Mathematics*

Tags: integration, notation, differential-forms

On page 348 of Shifrin's *Multivariable Mathematics*, for a 1-form $\omega=\sum F_{i}dx_{i}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and a parameterized curve $C$ given by a function $\mathbf{g}:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$, he defines$$\intop_{C}\omega=\int_{[a,b]}\mathbf{g}^{*}\omega=\int_{a}^{b}F_{i}\left(\mathbf{g}\left(t\right)\right)g_{i}^{\prime}\left(t\right)dt.$$

Why does he write $$\int_{[a,b]}\mathbf{g}^{*}\omega$$ and not$$\int_{a}^{b}\mathbf{g}^{*}\omega\ ?$$

I vaguely recall the $\int_{[a,b]}$ notation as referring to an unsigned definite integral, but may have got that wrong.

Comment: Ted participates on this site and will probably reply, but it seems to me the answer is on the first page of Chapter 8: he's trying to emphasize the connection to Stokes's theorem on manifolds, so he wants to emphasize thinking about $[a,b]$ as a manifold. $\int_{[a,b]}$ looks more like $\int_M$ than $\int_a^b$. The notation $M$ doesn't explicitly indicate that the manifold $M$ is *oriented*, so we shouldn't complain too much that the notation $[a,b]$ doesn't indicate the orientation of the interval.

Comment: @symplectomorphic - Hidden in plain sight at the start of the chapter. I should have seen that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vaguely recall from where?! At this point, we've defined the integral of a differential form over a parametrized manifold (perhaps with boundary). The notation $\int_a^b f(t)\,dt$ is the classical notation for the Riemann integral of the function $f$.

Comment: My vague recall was (I've remembered!) from Tao's *Differential Forms and Integration*. He calls $\int_{[a,b]}f\left(x\right)dx$ the *unsigned definite integral*, in contrast to the *signed definite integral* $\intop_{a}^{b}f\left(x\right)dx$.

Comment: LOL, well, I can't be responsible for every author's notation. :) I have been pretty careful about writing $\int_R$ even for multiple integrals and using the up-down notation only once we convert to iterated integrals.

Comment: I'm shocked! Shocked that all mathematicians don't use the same notation.

Comment: Be more shocked. I have never seen Tao's notation before and am not sure I even know what it should mean. I think this must be pretty much unique to him.

Comment: Oh, I see ... He's trying to cover the case of integrating on the interval $[a,b]$ when $b<a$. Too confusing at this level.

Comment: @Peter4075 I'm not sure if your last comment is a joke or not haha. I think the sensible reaction is to be shocked when two different mathematicians *use the same* notation.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz - I'm showing my age. It's from the classic 1942 film Casablanca. Captain Renault (as he quickly pockets his winnings): "I'm shocked! Shocked to find that gambling is going on in here."